# Boundary value problem PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Solve this boundary value problem:
$$
u_{xx}=0,u (0,y)=y^2,u (1,y)=1
$$
Where u is a function of x and y:
$$
u=u (x,y)
$$
And x varies from 0 to 1:
$$
0 <x<1
$$
And y varies from:
$$
-\infty <y<\infty
$$

Comment: In general, we don't just take a homework problem and do it for you.  You have to at least show what you've tried, what you understand, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we solve this equation just by integrating u:
$$
u (x,y)=c_1 (y)x+c_2 (y)
$$
Now if we use boundary conditions:
$$u (0,y)=y^2  \rightarrow  c_2=y^2$$
$$u (1,y)=1   \rightarrow  (c_1+c_2)=1 \rightarrow c_1=1-y^2$$
So we have:
$$
u (x,y)=(1-y^2)x+y^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

If we use separation of variables assuming $u(x,y)=X (x)Y (y) $ then we have:
$$
X''Y=0
$$
If $Y=0$ we have trivial solution which is not desirable so:
$$
X''=0
$$
It means:
$$
X (x)=c_1x+c_2
$$
Now if we use boundary conditions:
$$u (0,x)=X (0)Y (y)  \rightarrow  c_2Y (y)=y^2$$
$$u (1,x)=X (1)Y (y)   \rightarrow  (c_1+c_2)Y (y)=1$$
Is it correct? ?

Comment: Separation of variables does not really work well here. There is an easier way to proceed: think of $y $ as just fixed and then solve the ODE BVP.

Comment: It gives a function of x. How about y and the boundary condition??

Comment: You just think of the BC as being parametrized by $y $ and solve it. In other words if you could solve $u''=0,u (0)=4,u (1)=1$ then you can swap out for $u (0)=y^2$ just as well.

Comment: Is it allowed to do that??

Comment: Sure. In PDE terms, this is much like the method of characteristics.